# Attempting to set single value at Javascript array index. It is mass-assigning values instead

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am working on a matrix algorithm but have run into a problem early on.

I have the following array:

`[ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]`

I want to transform it into this:

`[ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 9, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]`

I am attempting to set the middle value like this:

```
array[1][1] = 9
```

In an isolated context this works fine. However, in the context of my recursive loop it is not working, and I wind up with this instead:

`[ [ 0, 9, 0 ], [ 0, 9, 0 ], [ 0, 9, 0 ] ]`

So my question is where have I gone wrong in my program?

```
function matrix(n, array = initArrays(n), i = 0, j = 0) {
  if (i > 0) {
    return array // <--- returns: [ [ 0, 9, 0 ], [ 0, 9, 0 ], [ 0, 9, 0 ] ]
  }

  array = addDigit(n, array, i, j)

  return matrix(n, array, i + 1, j)
}

function initArrays(n) {
  const array = []
  const subArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    subArray.push(0)
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array.push(subArray)
  }
  return array
}

function addDigit(n, array, i, j) {

  // array = [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ] // <--- uncommenting this line fixes the problem. Why? 

  array[1][1] = 9

  return array
}

matrix(3)
```

This is a simplified, contrived version of my program. It presently only recurs a single time, and sets the middle value of a 3x3 grid (ignore `j`, it is intended for future functionality).

It can be seen in action here:

**Non-working: What I want to fix**
https://repl.it/repls/AttentiveWideOrder

**Working: Hack solution**
https://repl.it/repls/CuteSoggyArchitects

The way the hack solution works is to manually reset the array immediately before attempting to assign my middle value. I have *no idea* why this makes any difference and would appreciate anyone who can point out my fault.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push independent arrays to the outer array. Javascript uses an object reference and you push the same reference to the outer array.

```js
function initArrays(n) {
  const array = []
  const subArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    subArray.push(0)
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array.push(subArray.slice());  // get copy of primitive values
  }
  return array
}


var array = initArrays(3);

array[1][1]= 9;

console.log(array);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I will review and attempt to implement it.

Comment: ok, that works great. I was confused about object references and that cleared it up. Much obliged.